# ASP.NET c#: "Cannot Create Instance of the abstract Class..." Then how?

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting, abstract

I'm tasked with creating several controls programatically.  It's DevExpress but a generic question.  The ASPxTextBox, ASPxComboBox and ASPxDateEdit have the same base class - ASPxTextBase.  I want to declare controls with many of the same settings from ASPxTextBase, then add the different editor's specific options later.  Like:

```
MakeControl(String Type, String Name, Int Length...)
{
    ASPxTextBase tbBase = new ASPxTextBase();
   tbBase.Name = Name;
   tbBase.Length = Length;

   ...
   if (Type == "COMBO")
        ... Cast tbBase to Combo Box
   if (Type = "DATE")
        ...  Case tbBase to DateEdit
```

But ASPxTextBase gives the error "Cannot Create Instance of the abstract Class...".   How can I share a method for this?

Comment: An **abstract** class cannot be instantiated - only inherited from (and those inherited classes can then be instantiated)

Comment: Please post the code for your base class as well as your deriving classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify it so you do in fact create an instance of the correct class, I imagine there is another way to do it but the following should work:

```
     ASPxTextBase MakeControl(String Type, String Name, int Length)
    {
        ASPxTextBase tbBase = null;

        switch (Type)
        {
            case "COMBO":
                tbBase = new ComboBox()
                {
                    Items = new List<string>()
                };
                break;

            case "DATE":
                tbBase = new DateEdit()
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now
                };
                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(Type));
        }

        tbBase.Name = Name;
        tbBase.Length = Length;

        return tbBase;

    }
```

I made some fake properties for what I imagined the Combo or Date types might have.

Comment: Thanks!  All great answers, I used this one because T scares me but I'm learning.  New to this object 'thing', i can use this little tip in many places.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an abstract class. You can declare one and inherit from one but you cannot create it. You need to create the concrete class first and then access the common properties on the base class:

```
MakeControl(String Type, String Name, Int Length...)
{
    ASPxTextBase tbBase = null;

   if (Type == "COMBO")
   {
        tbBase = new ASPxComboBox();
   }
   else if (Type = "DATE")
   {
        tbBase = new ASPxDateEdit();
   }

   tbBase.Name = Name;
   tbBase.Length = Length;

   ...
}
```

NOTE: I don't know the DevExpress class names so I've used dummy names in the code.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the type has a parameterless constructor you could use a generic method here. Passing in the type you wish to create as the generic parameter like so:

```
var dateControl = MakeControl<ASPxDateEdit>(“dateEdit1”, 50);
dateControl.Date = DateTime.Now;
```

Something along the lines of this; im on my phone so not syntax checked or tested but you get the idea.

```
T MakeControl<T>(String name, Int length) where T : ASPxTextBase, new()
{
    var control = new T();

    control.Name = name;
    control.Length = length;

    return control;
}
```